# selenium - search text in specific row of a table

Tags: java, selenium, html-table

I have a table that changes all the time.
I'm need to locate row that contains the word "All" and then to click on a link that placed in a cell of this particular row.
for example:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
    <td class="message_Content"> all cars </td> 
    <td><a class="Toggle" href="javascript:;">disable</a></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td class="message_Content"> renault </td>  
    <td><a class="Toggle" href="javascript:;">disable</a></td>
   </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
```

I want to find the row that contains the word "all" and then click on the word "disable" only in the same row.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should work. I did not tested the code but what you want to achieve is possible. Try the below code, you might need some twigs

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/thead/tr"));
        for (Iterator<WebElement> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            WebElement webElement = iterator.next();
            List<WebElement> findElement = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("./td"));
            if( findElement.size() > 0 ){
                if( findElement.get(0).getText() != null && findElement.get(0).getText().indexOf("all") != -1 ) {
                    List<WebElement> aElement = webElement.findElements(By.xpath("./td/a"));
                    aElement.get(0).click();
                                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```